# User authentication via android application in laravel 3 web service

Tags: php, web-services, laravel, laravel-3, android-webservice

I am using laravel 3 for my web application. As its outdated now so i am not getting any help for laravel3 for: android application integration with laravel 3.

**Problem:** when i submit get request to my web services but when i submit post request to login user, its not working. It is because of session_payload and laravel_session, every time laravel sending different session_apyload request to server. so how to send get that session_payload for android app and send it with post request to login user?

[image]

At this moment it will be very difficult for me to migrate from laravel 3 to laravel 5, so I am continuing in L3. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: you have to change in your routes.php file seems like your routes with name user/post-bbok except get request not post. you can change to Route::any('/user/post-book',array('uses' => 'UserController@postbook')

Comment: Its accepting post request and working fine in website but when i send post request via android or rest client plugin, it shows error 500 and when i include session_payload in header in rest client then allows me to login . But problem each time laravel changes session_payload value so how to get that value in application? here is my post route Route::post('signin', array('uses'=>'users@signin'));
Route::post('user/post-book', array('uses'=>'users@book_post'));